# Post and use the response SWIFT

Tags: php, swift, xcode

I want to post data to a php file, and use the JSON response to generate a table. I've just started trying to learn swift, so I have no idea where I've gone wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The swift file:

```
    func get(){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost/test.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "country=\(buttonPressedVal)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        do {
            let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/test.php")
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
            let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray

            print("Result -> \(result)")

        } catch {
            print("Error -> \(error)")
        }


        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

I want to use the result variable to generate a table view.

the php file:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=imoova","root","mysql");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST['country'])){
    $country = $_POST['country'];
}else{
    //$country = 'Australia';
    echo "Failed to get post\n";
}

try
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM imoova._relocation_deals A, imoova._airport_codes_lookup B  WHERE A.location_from = B.code AND B.country = :country AND A.active = 1";
    $result = array();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":country", $country);
    $stmt->execute();   
    while($result = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}       
?>
```

The error I get is: Error -> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines in your php code:

```
    while($result = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

You are generating multiple JSON in a single response. That is not a valid JSON. Try replacing the lines with something like this:

```
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $result[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
```